# How to monitor paging activity per process?

Tags: monitoring, swap, virtual-memory

I found that `vmstat` gives:

- si: Amount of memory swapped in from disk (/s)
- so: Amount of memory swapped to disk (/s)

(and here I understand that *swapping* and *paging* are being used interchangeably)

Is it possible to get those statistics for a specific process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't. Writing and reading to swap is done by kswapd.
There already was answer how it is [generally operates][1] - https://serverfault.com/a/316636/252390

If you wan't to reduce value of Swap IN/Out you may check `vm.swappiness` `sysctl` param.

```
sysctl vm.swappiness
```

You may set lower value to decrease swap usage in system. Generally it is set to 60.